# Java - How to run function synchronously for multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I must use three instances of the `Runnable` class named `changeCase` and only one single instance of the `Server` class for all three `changeCase` instances. The process execution needs to run continously, that is why I have used `while (true)` inside the overridden `run` method. The `process` method execution for each Thread is overlapping. How can I solve this issue?

**My code:**

```
package uppercase;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Server {

    void process(String threadName) {

        System.out.println("You are inside the Server " +threadName);

        System.out.println("Enter your sentence");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Press 1 to convert to Uppercase or Press 2 to convert to Lowercase");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc2.nextInt();

        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                changetoUpperCase(input);
                break;
            case 2:
                changetoLowerCase(input);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid number given\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    void changetoUpperCase(String msg) {

        printMessage(msg.toUpperCase());
    }

    void changetoLowerCase(String msg) {

        printMessage(msg.toLowerCase());
    }

    void printMessage(String msg) {

        System.out.println("[ " +msg+ " ]\n\n");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class changeCase implements Runnable {

    String threadName;
    Server target;
    Thread t;

    public changeCase(Server c, String s) {

        this.threadName = s;
        this.target = c;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void run() {

        while(true) {

            target.process(threadName);
        }

        //target.process(threadName);
    }

}

public class UpperCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server s1 = new Server();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new changeCase(s1, "Thread1"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new changeCase(s1, "Thread2"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new changeCase(s1, "Thread3"));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

}
```

**The output I need:**

```
run:
You are inside the Server Thread1
Enter your sentence
hello world
Press 1 to convert to Uppercase or Press 2 to convert to Lowercase
1
[ HELLO WORLD ]


You are inside the Server Thread3
Enter your sentence
HELLO WORLD
Press 1 to convert to Uppercase or Press 2 to convert to Lowercase
2
[ hello world ]


You are inside the Server Thread2
Enter your sentence
hello world
Press 1 to convert to Uppercase or Press 2 to convert to Lowercase
4
Invalid number given


You are inside the Server Thread3
Enter your sentence
```

**The output I am getting:**

```
run:
You are inside the Server Thread1
Enter your sentence
You are inside the Server Thread2
Enter your sentence
You are inside the Server Thread3
Enter your sentence
```

Comment: You could make `process()` method `synchronized`. Btw. you probably should reuse your `Scanner` instread of creating two instances.

Comment: @Amongalen how do I make it `synchronized`? Any hint?

Comment: @ShafiulIslamSajib by searching for "Java synchronized", you would quickly find https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: I don't quite see why you want multithreading here. The expected output shows a sequential program. If you want to gain benefits out of the multithreading you need to think about what parts of `process` can run parallel and what parts can't. Then you need to synchronize those sections accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method as below and it should work just fine.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            synchronized (target)
            {
                target.process(threadName);
                try {
                    target.wait();
                    notifyAll();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Since you do not want to make `process()` method as `synchronized`, so I placed `synchronized` keyword in `run()` method.

Why **it should work just fine** :

- The `synchronised` around the `process()` method call, allows only one `Thread` to access it at a time.
- Passing the `target` object in `synchronized` keyword as that is the resource that threads are working on.
- Once you have utilised the resource i.e the `process()` method is executed, need to `wait()` on the current `Thread` processing and `notifyAll()` other threads to take ownership.
- Calling `target.wait()` and not simply `wait()` because that uis the resource that threads are working on, otherwise it will throw `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner`.

Hope it answers your query.

You can go through some resources here.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/

Comment: "it should work just fine" can you justify that assertion? Why does this work? (It's not as helpful to say "this works" as it is to explain *why* it works).

Comment: If you just declare `process` synchronized, you effectively made the program run sequential.

Comment: Ya guys I got it ..thanks..just give me some time. I shall post the working code here.I am just bit lazy :P

Comment: Guys, I have updated the code and it works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to make thread execute one by one.

```
class Server {
int threadCount = 3;
volatile int i = 1;

synchronized void process(String threadName) {
    int thread = Integer.parseInt(threadName.substring(threadName.length() - 1));
    if (thread % threadCount != i) {
        return;
    }
    i = i == threadCount - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;

    System.out.println("You are inside the Server " + threadName);

    System.out.println("Enter your sentence");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc1.nextLine();
...
```